# Log in to Google Talk XMPP with non-Gmail account?

Tags: google, google-talk, xmpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect Google Talk with a non-Gmail Google account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28433/how-to-connect-google-talk-with-a-non-gmail-google-account)

I use username@mydomain.com to log into Google. I don't have/want Gmail. How do I connect Pidgin XMPP client to Google Talk?

I tried Username: user@mydomain.com, Domain: gmail.com, however it fails and says user@mydomain@gmail.com is an invalid XMPP name.

I can log in with the Gmail username I was forced to create when turning on my phone, but its stupid and I don't want to use it. I deleted Gmail but I can't get rid of the username, even though I don't use it to log into Google. I only made it up so my phone would work.